# Can we connect on premise CRM 2011 from Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, azure-data-factory, data-migration

We are trying to migrate the data from CRM 2011 to new version through Azure data factory but not sure if there is a option to connect to CRM 2011 which is on premise from Azure data factory.

Is there any way we can connect to CRM 2011 on premise from ADF.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-dynamics-crm-office-365), **Dynamics CRM ADF connector only  supports Dynamics versions 7 through 9 for both online and on-premises**. More specifically:

Version 7 maps to Dynamics CRM 2015.

Version 8 maps to Dynamics CRM 2016 and the early version of Dynamics 365.

Version 9 maps to the later version of Dynamics 365.

Comment: So is there any indirect way through which we can connect to CRM 2011 database to azure SQL and then access that azure SQL database from Azure data factory for migration of data.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Since this version is not even supported in ADF, there is no workaround as per my knowledge. you can explore here for any other approach: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/291898/how-to-migrate-data-from-crm-2011-to-dynamics-365-crm/837675

Comment: You could consider upgrading the on-premise installation to 2013 and then to 2015. Any custom plugins/javascript might have trouble after the update, but if the point is to pull out data, that might not matter.